# Derivation of interval Newton's method

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, interval-arithmetic

Saw this formula in my text on interval analysis
$$X^{(k+1)} = X^{(k)} \cap N(X^{(k)}) \\
k = 0,1,2,...$$
Where 
$$N(X^{(k)}) = m(X^{(k)}) - \frac{F(m(X^{(k)}))}{F'(X^{(k)})})$$
X is an interval say [a,b] . While it is similar to the ordinary Newton's method, I can't figure out how to deal with the intersection.
Can someone help prove this or rather point me to a material where the formula was derived

Comment: You have some notation to explain here, including $m$ and also the meaning of $F'$ applied to an interval.

Comment: The $m$ is the midpoint of the interval, for an interval $X = [a,b]$ $m(X)$ would be $\frac{a+b}{2}$, in the case of F' it's the inverse of the function F

Comment: That does not tell me how to calculate $F'(X)$.

Comment: F is just a normal function on $x$, just like $f(x)$ only this one is acting on an interval. The $f$ on the Newton's normal method $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$ didn't have to be defined to show that the formula, could generate sequence of $x$, approximate value for the root sought for.

Comment: Am thinking I'll take this normal case as a starting point, and then change the $x$ which is a real to $X$ which is an interval of reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of two intervals $[a_1,b_1]$, $[a_2,b_2]$ is empty if $b_1<a_2$ or $b_2<a_1$, else it is $$[\max(a_1,a_2),\min(b_1,b_2)].$$

If $x^*$ is a root in $X=[a,b]$, then $0=f(x^*)=f(m)+f'(\xi)(x^*-m)$ for some $\xi\in[a,b]$. Thus $x^*\in N(X)$, but other points in the derivative might lead to points outside the interval. Thus the intersection to keep the complexity of the resulting sets down.